# java.lang.NullPointerException is getting generating

Tags: java, selenium

Why is below happening and how can i use this under the `EnglishHomepage` ?

my code(not working) :

```
public class EnglishHomepage {

    WebDriver driver = null; 

    public Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    By login_button = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/a[15]");


    //constructor of EnglishHomepage
    public EnglishHomepage (WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver; 
    }

    public void clickFogotPassword() {
        driver.findElement(login_button ).click();
    }


    public void clickDropdownValue() {

        action.doubleClick(driver.findElement(xpath2)).perform();   

    }
}
```

code (working)

```
public class EnglishHomepage {

    WebDriver driver = null; 

    By login_button = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/a[15]");


    //constructor of EnglishHomepage
    public EnglishHomepage (WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver = driver; 
    }

    public void clickFogotPassword() {
        driver.findElement(login_button ).click();
    }


    public void clickDropdownValue() {

        **Actions action = new Actions(driver);**
        action.doubleClick(driver.findElement(xpath2)).perform();   

    }
}
```

I can use `public Actions action = new Actions(driver);` under the `clickDropdownValue` method and test is working fine as expected.

however,

when i move `public Actions action = new Actions(driver);` under the class, could see `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

exception

> at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.(Actions.java:65)  at
>   pages.EnglishHomepage.(EnglishHomepage.java:12)     at
>   testcases.Tc4_Market_status.click(Tc4_Market_status.java:27)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
>     at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: please refer the updated  question, i mean under EnglishHomepage

Comment: Do not initialize WebDriver driver = null;

Comment: @NagarjunaYalamanchili It's redundant, but it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `new Actions(driver)` is locate *above* the constructor, it is executed before the constructor body, i.e. the value of `driver` will still be null.

If `new Actions(driver)` is locate *below* the constructor, it is executed after the constructor body, i.e. the value of `driver` will be the value passed to the constructor.

*Recommendation:* In a field initializer, never use another field that is not fully initialized in its own initializer, and never use a field declared later.

The correct way to do this is to initialize the field in the constructor too, where the value is available.

```
WebDriver driver; // No need to initialize to null, it's the default

public Actions action; // Don't initialize here

public EnglishHomepage (WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver; 
    this.action = new Actions(driver);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Actually, moving the field declaration down shouldn't have worked, according to the Java Language Specification, section [12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), which specifies this order of initialization (para-phrased):

> Allocate memory and call constructor, which is evaluated as follows:
>
> - If this constructor begins with `this(...)`, call the **other constructor**. Process that constructor invocation recursively using these same steps.
> - Otherwise, call the **superclass constructor**, either as specified with a `super(...)` statement, or implicitly call the no-arg superclass constructor.
> - Execute the **instance initializers** and **instance variable initializers** for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the **left-to-right order** in which they appear textually in the source code for the class.
> - Execute the rest of the **body of this constructor**.

As can be seen, the constructor body (except `this(...)` and `super(...)`) is always executed last, according to the specification, so moving the field declaration down below the constructor shouldn't have changed the fact that the `driver` field is `null` when the `action` field is initialized.

The recommendation given above is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using below code.

```
WebDriver driver; 

public Actions action=new Actions(driver);
```

it will for sure give null pointer exception because you have assigned driver as null.
so if you want to use driver  you can use below code.

```
WebDriver driver; 

public Actions action;

public EnglishHomepage (WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver = driver; 
    this.action = new Actions(this.driver); // now driver is initialized so it will not give null pointer exception. always assign value under constructor. when you are assigning value inline so current value is **null** 

}
```